# How do I create a certain control using Windows Forms in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, windows, forms, visual-c++

I am new to using Windows Forms in C++ (and just in general), and I am not exactly sure of the name or if it's even possible to do. 

Currently I am currently working on a school project in which we must make a program for an imaginary bookstore. I am trying right now to make a sort of list that shows what the "customer" is buying. I have to make it sort by price and ISBN and any other variable that the book has.

In essence I am trying to make something like the following: 
[image: Control]

I just need to know how to get started. I can't figure out what the name of the control is or how to even get it to sort every time the user clicks on the header.

Comment: what is your development environment? are you using visual studio ? visual c++? MFC?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a managed C++
Please look at 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/mfcandwindowsforms.aspx?fid=3422&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=2509859

Try to do your control same way.

Answer (score 0):

The WindowsForms control you are looking for is called a DataGrid

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear by your question, but if you are trying to access Windows Forms from standard c++ you are out of luck.  Windows Forms lives in the Managed world while c++ is unmanaged.  To use windows forms you'd have to switch to C++/CLI or C#.  Which if you are doing something for a school project may not be an option.

If it is an option to switch languages like that.  I'd start looking at C++/CLI documentation to get a feel for how things might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know Windows UI inner workings, I recommend you to stay away from .NET for now, and learn some basic things in C++ and WinAPI. Sometimes programming .NET (or C++ / COM) requires you to invoke unmanaged components/functions and you'll be glad you understand how the low-level things work.

If your project requires .NET, go on, but don't forget to make yourself some time to learn good-old Win32 / C++ programming.

Answer (score 0):

Please give some more details about the question Dalze->
is there any requirement about using managed controls?  or not using them?
What's your prof want you to learn from this exercise (and is how to use stack overflow to do your homework one of them)?

There's several ways to skin this cat.

If you are supposed to or want to used managed code:
DataGrid mentioned is a good simple database tool [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.aspx)

An sql database could also hold all the information and allows sorting on the various sub elements.

If you choose not to use managed code you can build a few simple objects to carry the information you need, then add some sort functions for each of the variables of interest.